# Ignore JOINS/PARTS/QUITS unless the user has recently talked in the channel

Tags: irc, irssi

I'm sitting in a channel with many users, and I'm not interested in the lot of joins/parts/quits, *unless* a user has said something (I do want to know when someone who I'm talking with leaves).

What I want to get is something like `/ignore -channels #channel * JOINS PARTS QUITS`, but with an option to not ignore these messages for users who have talked in (e.g.) the past hour.

Comment: If you do not mind manually cleaning up the chat, use `/scrollback levelclear -level quits,parts,join` (found at http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.network.irc.irssi.user/992).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WeeChat has this built in, under the name "smart filter". There have been attempts to implement similar functionality as an Irssi script:

- http://crshd.anapnea.net/2012/10/03/Smartfilter-for-Irssi/
- https://github.com/lifeforms/irssi-smartfilter
- https://scripts.irssi.org/scripts/recentdepart.pl